# Matching two alphabet within regex

Tags: python, regex

How to match a string with a two alpha characters that is in line with N and R.

```
import re

string = 'vvvEX(1)35-5'
print(re.search(r'(N|R|[EX])\([0-9]\)\S*', string)[0])
# X(1)35-5
# expected output: EX(1)35-5
```

Comment: `(?:EX|[NR])\(\d+\)\S*`? See https://regex101.com/r/btJYQa/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[EX]` matches a single `E` or a single `X`, while you want to match a `EX` substring.

You may use

```
(?:EX|[NR])\(\d+\)\S*
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/btJYQa/1)

**Details**

- `(?:EX|[NR])` - a non-capturing group matching either `EX`, `N` or `R` (same as `(?:EX|N|R)`)
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `\S*` - 0 or more non-whitespace characters.